# If I subclass a class, can I specify a certain subclass an instance variable should be?

Tags: swift, instance-variables, subclassing

I have an NSObject subclass, `BaseClass`. BaseClass is a placeholder class for a couple subclasses, `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`.  There is an instance variable that I have present on both of the subclasses. They're the same name, and are both of a corresponding subclass of another object. They're often used in very similar ways, so I wanted to move some functionality from my SubClassA and SubClassB to the BaseClass. However, I need access to that variable.

If I move the variable into the `BaseClass`, I am unable to specify the proper subclass of it in `SubClassA` and `SubClassB`, saying I can't override it.  If I use the common parent class of this instance variable in the `BaseClass`, I lose some access to things that *aren't* common between how `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` work.

This is a more primitive example, but the basics of what I'm trying to do. This example obviously does not work.  Are my only options to choose having to define common functionality within `SubClassA` and `SubClassB` or is there a proper way to achieve my goal here?

```
class BaseClass: NSObject {
    var myObject: MyObject
}

class SubClassA: BaseClass {
    override var myObject: MyObjectA
}

class SubClassB: BaseClass {
    override var myObject: MyObjectB
}

class MyObject: NSObject { }

class MyObjectA: MyObject { }

class MyObjectB: MyObject { }
```

This gives me the error:

> Property 'myObject' with type 'MyObjectA' cannot override a property with type 'MyObject'

Comment: I really appreciate the multitude of different answer that solve this problem. Without knowing terminology, it was difficult to search for what I was trying to do. It's cool to see so many different possible methods to do this, and I've got some more guided research to be doing now than the blind google searching I was before. I wish I could select multiple right answers.

Comment: I think you should identify the problem first. What you’re trying to do is called co-variance & contra-variance. Changing a Type in subclass sometimes is possible, sometimes it’s not. If it’s exactly like your example, there are two options: 1. Either your design has flaws and you’re not following the Linkskov protocol, or 2. You should use generics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using generic? For simplicity, I removed NSObject

```
class MyObject {

}

class MyObjectA: MyObject {

}

class MyObjectB: MyObject {

}

class BaseClass<T> where T : MyObject {
    var myObject: T?
}

class SubClassA: BaseClass<MyObjectA> {
}

class SubClassB: BaseClass<MyObjectB> {
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this looks like what I was looking for! I often forget generics exist, have yet to put them into practice too much. Seems like as good a time to learn as any, other than a few years ago. I'll try it out and mark this as correct when it works.

Comment: @JakeT. I hope it can help. There are also other technics about subclassing. I would like to advertise my [article](https://medium.com/@cnliusen/swift-use-self-to-let-subclass-return-instances-of-subclass-6c7915833bf3)  : ).

Comment: The one hiccup was that I separate my delegate methods into extensions, and @objc does not currently support extensions of generics (or subclasses of generics). The fix was just moving those delegate methods into the original definition. `class BaseClass<T>: NSObject, DelegateProtocol where T:ServiceViewController {` is the format, for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of putting the `myObject` related code into `BaseClass`, you could put it into a protocol extension.  Consider this:

```
class BaseClass {
}

class SubClassA: BaseClass, HasMyObject {
    var myObject: MyObjectA
}

class SubClassB: BaseClass {
    var myObject: MyObjectB
}

class MyObject { }

class MyObjectA: MyObject { }

class MyObjectB: MyObject { }

protocol HasMyObject {
    associatedtype MyObjectClass

    var myObject: MyObjectClass { get set }
}
```

This is conceptually very similar to using generics, but would separate your `myObject` related code from the rest of the code in your class. Whether this is actually preferable over generics depends on your coding style and specific use-cases.

Comment: Hmmm, I like the look of this more, but it would require more rework than the accepted answer. If I was starting from scratch, I'd probably go this route, as it is, the generic was pretty quick to implement

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class function in your `BaseClass` that returns a class that inherits from a `BaseObject` (myObject) and override it for whichever class you need.

```
class BaseClassObject: NSObject {

}

class BaseClass: NSObject {
    func generateClass() -> NSObject {
        return BaseClassObject()
    }
}

class BranchedObject: BaseClassObject {

}

class SubClassA: BaseClass {

    var myObject: NSObject?

    override func generateClass() -> NSObject {
        return BranchedObject()
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.myObject = self.generateClass()
    }

}
```